# how to avoid null in for(string sth : array) java

Tags: java, arrays, null

I'm new in java, and currently studying it with making & trying in various ways.

I'm trying to printout values in array without null, using for(String sth : array) grammar. So I tried it first like,

```
for(String sth : arr){
    if(arr[sth] != null)
    System.out.println(arr[sth]);
}
```

but it didn't work, so I tried also like

```
for(String sth : arr){
  if(arr[Integer.valueOf(sth)] != null)
  System.out.println(arr[Integer.valueOf(sth)]);
}
```

but it didn't work too.

Is it possible to avoid null values, without using this method below ?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
   if(arr[i] != null)
}
```

(I searched my question in this site for 30min, but I can't find any questions similar with mine so I write this question. Did I misunderstand a basic Java grammar ?)

Any comments would be glad to me.

Comment: Just a comment: this kind of thing (code testing for nulls) is often a sign that there is a problem in your design or implementation.  It is often better to avoid this by 1) not allowing nulls there in the first place, or 2) if this an "array implementing a list" by moving the nulls to the end and keeping track of the last non-null index.

Comment: Also: you shouldn't just say "but it doesn't work".  Tell us *how* it doesn't work.  (Compilation error?  NPE?  Something else?)

Comment: `sth` is a pointer to the array entry itself, not an array index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for-each` can be read like like for each **element** `sth` in the array (do something). Like

```
for (String sth : arr) {
    if (sth != null) {
        System.out.println(sth);
    }
}
```

**or**, in Java 8+,

```
Stream.of(arr).filter(x -> x != null).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. It really helped me.